# Site crashes when deleting a field

Tags: 8, features

Whenever I delete a field I get WSOD with following error:

> Drupal\Core\Field\FieldException: Attempt to create a configurable
>   field of non-configurable field storage variations. in
>   Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig->getFieldStorageDefinition() (line 315
>   of core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldConfig.php).

This site was created by taking a minimally setup site and using Features, I migrated over bundle configuration from another site. Features can't do this without continually failing due to dependency errors. For many of these errors; the only solution was to delete the yml file causing the issue. My guess is that Features has somehow corrupted my site, but:

- the field is deleted despite the crash (as far as I can tell)
- this issue occurs even for fields and bundles which existed prior to any Feature modules being enabled
- this issue occurs even for new bundles and new fields that I create after Features migration has been done
- the bundles which were migrated using Features all appear to work correctly in as far as I can add new fields and I can add new entities.

I have done cache rebuild, run cron and run db update.

Also of note: the original site which the configuration was migrated from runs as a multisite on the same docroot. This means it has the same composer installed version of Drupal 8.8.1 as well as all the same modules and same versions of those modules as the site which does not work. The original site has no issues deleting fields.

## EDIT

4k4's comments below led me to this Commerce issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3100553

but still no luck. After "completely" uninstalling Commerce i still get his error when trying to delete a field:

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The
>   "commerce_product" entity type does not exist. in
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (line 150 of
>   core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager.php).

Comment: Is the error message for the field you are deleting or for a different field?

Comment: Interesting question. Only info I see is error posted above, which doesn't mention which field the issue is with. I enabled stack trace in devel, but still no other info. So I assume issue is with the field I'm deleting. Also, I've added a new bundle and added 1 field and then removed that field and error occurs, so no other fields on the bundle.

Comment: The error message contains the field name: `variations`

Comment: Thanks @4k4, I don't really have a field called variations but this sounds like a Commerce issue and led me here: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3100553. I have moved my search for a fix there but will update post above with latest... it seems like just a D8 mess that will require a lot of manual db cleanup.